# In a Hausdorff space, is a set a subset of its derived set: i.e., is $A\subset A'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$. Let $p\in A$. Then, there exists a sequence that converges to $p$, i.e., the sequence
$\{p_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ s.t. $\forall n[$$p_n = p]$. Thus, $p$ is a limit point of $A$, since there exists a sequence of points in $A$ that converge to it. So, $p\in A'$.

This is almost definitely wrong, I presume--but why?

Comment: $p$ is a limit point of $A$ if there is a sequence of distinct points of $A$ converging to $p$.

Comment: For the record, if the space $X$ isn't sequential, limit points (or adherent points) may not be accessible by sequences. If you want a sequence-like argument you need nets.

Comment: You've only made the trivial observation that each set is a subset of its sequential closure. Nothing about $A'$ at all.

Comment: If you take $\mathbb R$ with the topology whose open sets are $\emptyset$ and "any subset of $\mathbb R$ which contains $\{1\}$" then the derived set of $A=\{1\}$ in this topology is $\mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$, so it entirely possible for a set to be disjoint from its derived set.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus $p$ is a limit point of $A$.

This is not correct. The fact that there is a sequence of points in $A$ converging to $p$ implies that $p$ lies in the closure of $A$. But it might not be a limit point of $A$.

To show that $p$ is a limit point of $A$, it suffices to show that there exists a sequence of points in $A\setminus \{p\}$ converging to $p$.

And the fact that it is Hausdorff has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Hi, I just added a single character `>` at the beginning of your answer, to indicate that you were quoting something from the original question. Feel free to remove it if you wish.